# Get compass direction in c

Tags: c, compass, direction

I calculated the distance between two coordinates and the angle between them using harvesine formula, I want to get the direction of the compass but Im having problems, I found this code to get direction  but i cant get the index.
Please help fixing this part

```
int degree = 30;

char cordNames [] = {'N', 'NE', 'E', 'SE"]', 'S', 'SW', 'W', 'NW', 'N'};
int  coordinateIndex = floor(((degree-22.5)%360)/45);

if(coordinateIndex <0)
{
    coordinateIndex=coordinateIndex+8;
}

result = directions[index+1];
```

Comment: It's ["Haversine" formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula). And what exactly is the issue you're having? Are you getting compiler errors or weird runtime bugs or is the implementation incorrect...?

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so e.g. I would know more information about the types of `result` and `directions`. Also I don't think you're `'SE"]'` is supposed to look like that? Typo I take it?

Answer (score 1):

There are all sorts of errors here. You are referencing `result`, `directions`, and `index`, which have never been defined; you cannot have two letter character variables, you must use C-style strings (character arrays), i.e., an array within an array essentially, for example:

```
const char *coord_names[] = { "N", "NE", "E", "SE", "S", "SW", "W", "NW", "N" };
```

Also in your line `int  coordinate_index = floor(((degree - 22.5) % 360) / 45);`, this is incorrect C and won't compile; the `%` modulo operator is only for integers; your `degree - 22.5` returns a double automatically, so you must use the `fmod()` function instead or cast or also use the floor function or something similar (you most likely wanted `fmod()` though?? I'm not sure) on `degree - 22.5`.

And of course I'm sure you are already `#include`ing `<math.h>`, but just make sure you don't forget to link with `-lm` also to link to the math library (for `floor()` and if you choose to use `fmod()`).